# Node JS child process with async/await

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, async-await, child-process

i am using `const { spawn } = require('child_process');`
this process calls a file which is a scheduler that checks for an entry in DB in the last 30 mins.
the scheduler service calls a method to run the query but the process doesn't wait for the query.
I am confused as to how to use promises inside the child process. i need the result of query for further use in the scheduler.

here is my query function

```
const getReviewFilledInLastThirtyMins = () => {
  console.log('comes here for query');
  let queryFilter = {
    createdAt: {
      // 30 minutes ago (from now)
      $gt: new Date().getTime() - 30 * 60 * 1000
    }
  };
  return models.Review.find(queryFilter).exec();
};
```

Comment: Where and how are you calling this `getReviewFilledInLastThirtyMins` method?

Comment: `const checkIsReviewFilled = async () => {
  console.log('...................');
  let reviewInLastThirtyMins = getReviewFilledInLastThirtyMins();}` i am callling it in another function like this.

Comment: You need to use `await` keyword with that  `let reviewInLastThirtyMins = await getReviewFilledInLastThirtyMins();`

Comment: Give this doc a read. https://nodejs.dev/en/learn/modern-asynchronous-javascript-with-async-and-await

Comment: it doesn't help me. i tired using await but there is something not working with child process.@MuhammadUsama

Comment: I don't understand why it's not working within a process which I spawned @MuhammadUsama

Comment: Are you using await with `checkIsReviewFilled` method as well? if not then you need to add await when you are calling `checkIsReviewFilled` method

Comment: I had the same issue! have you created the db connection in child process ?